# .wav C++ data not outputting correctly

Tags: c++

So I know I have asked this question before, however, I am still stuck and before I can move on with my project. Basically, I'm trying to read in a .wav file, I have read in all of the required header information and then stored all the data inside a char array. This is all good, however, I then recast the data as an integer and try and output the data.

I have tested the data in MatLab, however, I get very different results:

Matlab -0.0078

C++: 1031127695

Now these are very wrong results, and someone kindly from here said it's because I'm outputting it as an integer, however, I have tried pretty much every single data type and still get the wrong results. Someone has suggestion that it could be something to do with Endianness (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) .. Does this seem logical?

Here is the code:

```
bool Wav::readHeader(ifstream &file)
{

file.read(this->chunkId,                                 4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->chunkSize),     4);
file.read(this->format,                                  4);

file.read(this->formatId,                                4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->formatSize),    4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->format2),       2);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->numChannels),   2);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->sampleRate),    4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->byteRate),      4);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->align),         2);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->bitsPerSample), 4);

char testing[4] = {0};
int testingSize = 0;

while(file.read(testing, 4) && (testing[0] != 'd' ||
                                testing[1] != 'a' ||
                                testing[2] != 't' ||
                                testing[3] != 'a'))
{

file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&testingSize), 4);
file.seekg(testingSize, std::ios_base::cur);

  }

      this->dataId[0] = testing[0];
      this->dataId[1] = testing[1];
      this->dataId[2] = testing[2];
      this->dataId[3] = testing[3];
     file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->dataSize),     4);

     this->data = new char[this->dataSize];

     file.read(data,                     this->dataSize);

     unsigned int *te;

     te = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&this->data);

     cout << te[3];

     return true;
     }
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I hope I've given enough details.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your _expected_ output?

Comment: Expected: -0.0078 Actual: 1031127695

Comment: How do you expect to get a floating point number from an integer? Also, do the file contain 32 or 16 bit samples?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've tried to use float, get another weird result.. I think it's 16 bit, I'm not at home atm so can't compile the code.. Do you think this problem can be resolved? I don't see where I am going wrong and it's annoying me

Comment: Guessing and testing and posting on Stack Overflow is far inferior to just debugging the code. Instead of focusing on the final result, you need to figure out the point of failure, which is likely further up in the code somewhere.

Comment: @tenfour mhm, I use G++ through terminal to compile, I was unaware you can debug.. Weird

Comment: The endianness question is easy to answer. Do you get sensible values for `chunkSize`, `numChannels`, `sampleRate` etc. If not then endianness is an issue (along with whatever other issues you might have).

Comment: I'm curious why you are expecting the value to be floating point, but you cast to an int.

Comment: Going by this page https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/ the sample data can either by 8 bits or 16 bits. You said above you think it's 16 bit, in that case the correct cast is probably `reinterpret_cast<short*>` not `reinterpret_cast<int*>`. But that still won't work if you have endianness issues. Your basic mistake is thinking that you can rely on casts for this kind of work, in general you can't. Your other mistake seems to be thinking that MatLab got it right.

Comment: If you cannot debug, you cannot code. SO is definitely an inferior debugger to the multitude of existing debuggers that operate just fine in a terminal, for example gdb. If you insist on not using a real debugger, at least use `cout` to narrow the problem down. "wall of code yields incorrect output" is not a sensible problem statement.

Comment: Does the file contain 32-bit linear samples? (i.e. do you get a value of 1 in `format2` and 32 in `bitsPerSample`)? Is your platform little-endian, with a 32-bit `int` type?

Comment: The beauty of binary data: Even binary data is formatted and you need to know what format it is in. Since it is generally not readable it is hard to debug. Endianess is the complication you get with integers and you may be lucky that this is the entire difference with floating points but this is by no means guaranteed. From looking at the Wikipedia entry it seems the most likely content is a sequence of 16 bit entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there're several issues with your code. One of them are the casts, for instance this one:

```
 unsigned int *te;                           
 te = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&this->data);     // (2)
 cout << te[3];
```

**te** is a pointer to **unsigned int**, while you try to cast to a pointer to **int**. I would expect compilation error at line (2)...

And what do you mean by **te[3]**? I expect some garbage from ***(te + 3)** memory location to be outputed here.

Comment: Sorry, how is this possible? I have to declare a new int array called "te" to store the data inside.. Ok, even if I reinterpret it as an unsigned int I still get wrong results.. I don't see how te[3] would print garbage.

Comment: sorry, I haven't noticed that "te" is an array in fact. But, as someone already pointed out, you cannot expect floating point number printed out when you're using an array of integers... It would be probably helpful if you could show us the declaration of your Wav class.